# How to reply on click on InlineKeyboardButton in c# (TelegramBot)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to show some message when the users click on an `InlineKeyboardButton`. How can I do this?

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new[] // first row
                {
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("برنامه های آموزش",@"perss"),
                    new InlineKeyboardButton("سوابق پرسنل","sdf"),
                }

            });
            
            await Task.Delay(500); // simulate longer running task

            await Bot1.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "یکی از موارد زیر را انتخاب نمایید.",
                replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

When user click inline button, you will recive a [callback_query](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) object.

You can use [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) method to show alert message,
maybe with `show_alert` parameter.